# curl extension is already enable but still getting error

Tags: curl

[image]

I am not using WAMP or XAMP and Im using windows 10.

I also restarted apache and ensured that the correct  php.ini is loaded but still getting

```
Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could give us a hint to what you are using? Windows? Linux - which one? MAMP?

Comment: ops sorry, its windows, mac and linux does not have dll extension

Comment: There is no "dll" in your question.

Answer (score 0):

most likely, you get an error during php initialization, in which case, shame on you for not checking the error logs (or perhaps, error logging is even disabled?)

make sure your php.ini has

`log_errors=On
error_reporting=E_ALL
error_log=/path/to/error.log`

then use phpinfo();  to verify that the settings are actually set at runtime.

then check the error logs. it should contain the error saying why php_curl.dll failed to load. (my best guess: php_openssl.dll has not yet been loaded, which php_curl.dll depends on. in which case, make sure that php_openssl.dll is loaded *BEFORE* php_curl.dll )